# CakeDC search from multiple table

Tags: forms, cakephp, search, if-statement, cakedc

I use cakedc for search function in my cakephp application.

The search has a dropdown for categories.
I want the search go to the respective model/controller based on the dropdown.

```
<php echo $this->Form->create('Fashion', array(
    'url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'search'), $this->params['pass'])));
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('div' => false, 'empty' => true, 'label'=>''));
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('div' => false, 'empty' => 'All', 'label'=>'', 'class' => 'dropdown_categories',
                'options'=>array(array(1 => 'Fashion', 
                                        2 => 'Books, Games & Music', 
                                        3 => 'Electronic Gadget', 
                                        4 => 'Gifts, Toys & Hobbies',
                                        5 => 'Health & Beauty',
                                        6 => 'Homes, Garden & Tools',
                                        7 => 'Sports',
                                        8 => 'Automotives'))));
```

with this coding, its only search items in fashion table.
I have tables: fashions, books, electronics, gifts and many more.
How can I change the "**$this->Form->create('Fashion');**" based on the dropdown.

is there any better way to solve this. Either using if else or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** a search index plugin. The plugin implements the PRG pattern as stated [here](https://github.com/cakedc/search/tree/master#post-redirect-get-concept) in the readme.md. If your tables are not related, and they don't seem so, you'll need to implement a search index or better use a dedicated DB like Elastic Search for it. The search plugin can then be used to filter that index.

If and **only** if your tables are related you can search across them. The documentation in [the develop branch](https://github.com/cakedc/search/tree/develop) was updated and is awaiting its merge to master. [See the example section](https://github.com/CakeDC/search/blob/develop/Docs/Documentation/Examples.md) of how to search across **related** tables.